# Only Get First Part Of Error Description Message in SSIS Package

Tags: c#, sql, ssis

I have an ssis package that writes information into a table when it fails.
Some of the information is the system variable ErrorDescription. 
My question is how do I only get the first part of the ErrorDescription and not the whole message as it sometimes get too long and doesn't contain useful information and I have to generate report on the errors and the error message is too long for the report.

Thanking you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it were me, I would want to get the entire message into the table every time, and just limit the characters I select for the report if it's too long.   But if you don't store the entire error message, you might regret it the one time you chop off some useful information.

However, you can limit the characters you store by using the LEFT() function in the SQL command where you store the error information in the table.

Comment: I was also thinking of storing the whole error message and then when the report is generated use the sql Left function or the c# Substring function (as the report is generated in c#)...I just thought that there might be another way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You can [use Event Handler](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/ssis/ssis-event-handlers-basics/) on [required](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140223.aspx) event by choosing right executable, then by using Script Task/Component you can put your logic to extract the error description.

I am not aware of what exactly your package does, but if it's feasible then something like from below articles can be implemented.

[Get error descriptions](http://consultingblogs.emc.com/jamiethomson/archive/2005/08/08/SSIS-Nugget_3A00_-Get-error-descriptions.aspx)

[How to get error description in ssis](http://discoversql.blogspot.co.uk/2013/04/how-to-get-error-description-in-ssis.html)

[Getting error column name in ssis](http://naseermuhammed.wordpress.com/tips-tricks/getting-error-column-name-in-ssis/)